# OpenVPN Clients timeout on connection

Tags: linux, networking, openvpn, raspbian

I originally asked this on Server Fault, and they forwarded me to Stack Exchange who forwarded me to here. Source:https://serverfault.com/questions/896424/openvpn-clients-fail-to-connect

I would like to apologize ahead of time for my ignorance (I know I have little knowledge in this topic). I recently purchased a Raspberry Pi, and since I had no immediate use for it I set it up as an OpenVPN server using a script called PiVPN in the Raspbian OS. It works very quickly and is relatively painless aside from the key generation.

The issue is after about 36 hours of the server being up, with 3 or more keys in use, clients just can't connect. The output for    `systemctl status openvpn`    shows the service is active (exited), and this is displayed at all times when it does and does not work. The `/var/log/openvpn.log` states that it cannot determine IPv4/IPv6 and then claims to use something called AF_INET. It then says  that it's listening for incoming TCP connections on AF_INET. As for the clients, they just time out, I haven't been able to view the logs since the clients are Android devices and the OS is locked down. New keys also have the same issue once the Pi reaches this "critical point."

The only way I've been able to work around this is to uninstall and then rerun the script and reissue the keys. When doing that, I set it up the exact same way as before, with TCP and the same port, same networking configurations. I'd appreciate some help to find a more permanent fix, and if you can spare some knowledge about other aspects to this topic I'd welcome that as well.

Comment: Tim, check out this post man.... I think you will find some helpful detail in this if you keep reading down through the thread.... This seems like relevant content with a potential solution so read carefully to ensure you don't miss what I saw with a quick eye scan and some super fast speed reading: https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=196362

Comment: So the site didn't really help my issue, and as a backup in the event I changed the OS or screwed it up further, I created a bootable iso to fall back on. I used it and the issue persisted. I ended up using Angristan's script for OpenVPN setup found on Github. I've been monitoring it closely and will let you know how it goes.

Comment: So about 24 hours after it went up successfully, my test decive lost connection to the server. I stopped the service on the Pi and then turned the Pi off entirely a few minutes later, then I restarted it 10 minutes later. After restarting it, everything went back to normal. I checked the logs around the time it went down, and other than HMAC authentication errors which isn't the source issue since it does that all the time, there was nothing out of the ordinary.